# Page not updating after localstorage value change, REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `this.state.language` that I manipulate via localstorage in app.js. However, I pass this value to my routes as a prop and whatever this value is, i have an if statement to load data from a json file. e.g if the value is 'en' it loads data from `data.en` or if it is 'es' it loads data from `data.es`. So my problem is whenever the localstorage value is toggled, it will load the correct data in the json, but if I switch page it doesn't. I've tried using `this.props`, `this.state` and not using state and instead getting it directly via `localstorage.getItem()`.

App.js

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: localStorage.getItem('language')
    }
    this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'}, () => localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language)));
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'}, () => localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language)));
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

Code on another page to load the json data depending on what the localstorage value is

```
class NewFormDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            language: this.props.language,
            siteName: '',
            counties: '',
            siteAddress: '',
            siteEmail: '',
            siteNumber: '',
            siteCat: '',
            openTimes: '',
            fees: '',
            access: '',
            gps: '',
            w3w: '',
            txtHeader: '',
            txtContent: ''
        };

    }

    validateForm() {
        if (this.state.siteName != '' &&
            this.state.siteAddress != '' &&
            this.state.siteEmail != '' &&
            this.state.siteNumber != '' &&
            this.state.openTimes != '' && 
            this.state.fees != '' && 
            this.state.access != '' && 
            this.state.gps != '' && 
            this.state.w3w != '' && 
            this.state.txtHeader != '' && 
            this.state.txtContent != '') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        this.props.history.push('/newSite/tours');
    }

    render() {

        let jsonLang;

        if (this.props.language == 'en') {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        } else if (this.props.language == 'es') {
            jsonLang = data.es;
        } else {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        }

        this.placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
        this.counties = jsonLang.counties;
        this.categories = jsonLang.categories;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing your language value incorrectly. You're *getting* it like this:

```
this.state = {
  sideNav: '',
  language: localStorage.getItem('language')
}
```

...but then storing it like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('language', JSON.stringify(this.state.language));
```

That means you end up with `"en"` (or `"es"`) in local storage (including the quotes), not `en` or `es`. Later when you refresh the page, that doesn't match any of your `data` items so you default to `data.en`.

Since `language` is a string, there's no need to use JSON. Just:

```
localStorage.setItem('language', this.state.language);
```

---

There's another problem: You're not allowing for when the page is loaded and there is no `language` value in `localStorage`. In your case, you can use the `||` idiom, since `localStorage.getItem` returns `null` if the item doesn't exist:

```
this.state = {
  sideNav: '',
  language: localStorage.getItem('language') || 'en'
};
```

(I've also added the missing `;` there.)

You probably want to go a step further and validate it:

```
const defLanguage = 'en';
let language = localStorage.getItem('language') || defLanguage;
if (!data[language]) {
    language = defLanguage;
}
this.state = {
  sideNav: '',
  language
};
```

You might even define `defLanguage` at the same level as `data` (and right next to it), so you can use it everywhere you apply a default.

---

As I mentioned in a comment on your previous question, when using `this.props.language` in the component(s), you can replace

```
if (this.props.language == 'en') {
    jsonLang = data.en;
} else if (this.props.language == 'es') {
    jsonLang = data.es;
} else {
    jsonLang = data.en;
}
```

with simply:

```
jsonLang = data[this.props.language] || data.en;
```

or if you do the `defLanguage` thing:

```
jsonLang = data[this.props.language] || data[defLanguage];
```